# Retrieve auto scaling group instance ip's and provide it to ansible

Tags: mongodb, ansible, terraform

Im currently developing terraform script and ansible roles in order to install mongodb with the replication. im using auto scaling group and i need to pass, ec2 instance private ip's to ansible as extra vars. is there any way to do that?

When it's come to rs.initiate() is there any way to add ec2 private ip to mongo cluster when terraform creating the instances.

Comment: Why do you want to run Ansible against an ASG after it has started? Normally you would, optionally bake as much as possible into an AMI and then have the rest of the configuration (for anything environment/instance specific) happen in the user data script. If you're relying on Ansible running against instances in an ASG then how do you intend to handle the ASG scaling out or replacing unhealthy instances? While this is technically possible I'd recommend against it and strongly encourage you to follow the normal approach above.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure about how it's done in ASGs, probably a combination of user-data and EC2 metadata would be helpful.

But I do it as below in case we have a fixed number of nodes. Posting this answer as it can be helpful to someone in some way.

Using EC2 dynamic inventory scripts.
Ref - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html

This is basically a python script i.e `ec2.py` which gets the instance private IP using tags etc. It comes with a config file named `ec2.ini`.

Tag your instance in TF script (you add a role tag) -

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {

  ....

  tags                    = "${merge(var.tags, map(
                            "description","mongodb-node",
                            "role", "mongodb-node",
                            "Environment", "${local.env}",))}"
}

output "ip" {
  value       = ["${aws_instance.ec2.private_ip}"]
}
```

Get the instance private IP in playbook -

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="MongoDB Node IP is - {{ hostvars[groups['tag_role_mongodb-node'][0]].inventory_hostname  }}"
```

Now run the playbook using TF `null_resource` -

```
resource null_resource "ansible_run" {

  triggers {
       ansible_file = "${sha1(file("${path.module}/${var.ansible_play}"))}"
      }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -i ./ec2.py --private-key ${var.private_key} ${var.ansible_play}"
  }
}
```

You got to make sure AWS related environment variables are present/exported for ansible to fetch AWS EC2 metadata. Also make sure `ec2.py` is executable.

If you want to get the private IP, change the following config in `ec2.ini` -

```
destination_variable = private_ip_address
vpc_destination_variable = private_ip_address
```

Comment: What happens when the ASG scales out or replaces an unhealthy instance? I don't think running Ansible (or any configuration tool) against an ASG is a good idea really.

Comment: ahh.. right, I answer I posted was for a fixed number of instances, i overlooked the ASG part. I completely agree that this isn't a viable solution with ASGs. With ASGs, it better to use user-data or packer kind tools. I will edit the answer.

Comment: ASG has warm pool, if you go with a preset amount of instances, start them all, run ansible on all them, and have them configured in `Stopped` state in the `warm_pool` settings, then you can run them this way.